# Wrapping specific XML nodes in tags using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform a dataset using XSLT. Only one section should get additional tags.

```
<formData>
    <baseFields>
        <elementA>TEST</elementA>
        <elementB>TEST2</elementB>
    </baseFields>
    <dataFields>
        <groupA>
            <elementA>TEST</elementA>
            <elementB>TEST2</elementB>
        </groupA>
        <groupB>
            <elementA>TEST</elementA>
            <elementB>TEST2</elementB>
        </groupB>
    </dataFields>
</formData>
```

into

```
<formData>
    <elementA>TEST</elementA>
    <elementB>TEST2</elementB>
    <groupA>
        <elementA><asCurrent>TEST</asCurrent></elementA>
        <elementB><asCurrent>TEST2</asCurrent></elementB>
    </groupA>
    <groupB>
        <elementA><asCurrent>TEST</asCurrent></elementA>
        <elementB><asCurrent>TEST2</asCurrent></elementB>
    </groupB>
</formData>
```

The baseFields group and the dataFields group should be removed and nodes or text elements within the dataFields section should be wrapped in asCurrent tags.

Any help will be appreciated!

**Update:**
Based on the help from Dan Field I was able to process this using the following XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="baseFields">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dataFields">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dataFields//text()">
            <asCurrent><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/></xsl:copy></asCurrent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is a simple identity transform with templates to match the tags you want to discard that just apply the next template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="baseFields">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dataFields">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

[XSLTransform](http://xsltransform.net/bwdwrT/1)

Comment: Your 1st template is redundant and can be removed. OTOH, adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` could be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i was able to use your XSLT as a base for my use case. I added <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> and added one additional match for text nodes under the dataFields tag to wrap them in the asCurrent tags

Comment: Thanks for the tips @michael.hor257k!